# Statistics for facebook like button

Tags: like

I have a small site with facebook like button.

I want to find out the information about what pages are liked.

I've found url http://graph.facebook.com/?id=http://imdb.com but it shows only overal count for the site. I think that I can ask http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=url1,url2 with all my pages as the parameters to get detailed information, but this seems to be an ugly solution.
A have lots of pages, so I have to ask facebook many times.

Maybe there is some simple way of finding the information I need?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Google Analytics for this](http://www.meadigital.com/clickosity/2011/08/google-analytics-social-media-guide/).

Answer (score 1):

Make Tech Easier recently [posted a walkthrough](http://maketecheasier.com/add-social-tracking-for-google-analytics/2011/08/04) for doing this with Google Analytics that doesn't involve registering an FB application. I'm actually not sure why that step is even there(in John's answer); it seems not to be for simply tracking the likes, but so that you can use the Facebook Insights tool in addition. If you want that, fine, but I had no call for it.

Answer (score 0):

Try Facebook Analytics: http://fa.baldsoft.com/
It's a free tool, enabling you to define list of URLs and then you get all the necessary statistics. If your web runs under WordPress, it's even easier, because it can read URLs directly from WP database.